# how to store values in a structure array

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem storing certain processed values in my program into a structure array.
These values contain 3 long integers, and I'm trying to store these values as arrays in my structure.

This is a simplified, relevant version of my whole code. Please help me make it work.

```
#include<iostream>
#define MAX 20

using namespace std;

struct DATA
{
    int id, number;
    float height;
} stuarray [MAX];

int main ()
{
 long int1 =0;      //contains integer values obtained from a file                                       
 long int2 =0;      //contains integer values obtained from a file
 long int3 =0 ;     //contains integer values obtained from a file

 cout<< stuarray[MAX].id << endl;
 cout<< stuarray[MAX].number << endl;
 cout<< stuarray[MAX].height << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

okay, i'll explain my program. im reading values from a file as a string. after this im supposed to split them into 3 parts and store them in an array. this arrays should refer to the member variables in the structure. 
i have managed to read the values, split them, and convert all 3 of them into long ints.
now i have to store these three values in the structure array.
thank you all for ur help.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you want here.

Comment: Suggestion: write your main() function as a unit test. Use some sample input values, then test your final values against what they should be and return 0 if it works or 1 if it does not. This will also let us know what you expect so we can help.

Comment: please note that stuarray[MAX] (or max - case sensitive!! and you defined max) will be out of bound.. counting starts from 0.

Comment: This "simplified, relevant version of [your] whole code" is what's known as a "testcase" in Q&A circles, and you did a fairly good job with it. Still, it's not clear what you're after; you provide one set of initial values, but don't tell us where you want to store them. What goes in each member of each of the twenty array elements?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal    okay, i'll explain my program. im reading values from a file as a string. after this im supposed to split them into 3 parts and store them in an array. this arrays should refer to the member variables in the structure. i have managed to read the values, split them, and convert all 3 of them into long ints. now i have to store these three values in the structure array. thank you all for ur help.

Comment: @anakin57: Might be best if you edit your question.

Answer (score 8):

To store values in a specific element of stuarray:

```
stuarray[i].id = something;
stuarray[i].number = somethingElse;
stuarray[i].height = aFloatThisTime;
```

And note that for an array of `MAX` entries, legal indexes are in the
range [0,MAX).

Comment: You give me a chance to see a Unicorn by mentioning about Array overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Either add 3 long int members to your struct, or add an array of length 3:

```
struct DATA
{
    int id, number;
    float height;
    long int value1, value2, value3;
} stuarray[MAX]
```

or

```
struct DATA
{
    int id, number;
    float height;
    long int values[3];
} stuarray[MAX]
```

If you want to use the latter example, storing values in the array would look something like:

```
stuarray[i].values[0] = int1;
stuarray[i].values[1] = int1;
stuarray[i].values[2] = int2;
```